# BlazeDS turnkey configuration for mysql

Tags: java, mysql, apache-flex, blazeds

What is the configuration and code required to use mysql within a BlazeDS turnkey environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply deploy BlazeDS on Tomcat with your application, and you may have to setup a custom channel if the default won't do (it usually is fine as it is.) Generally speaking though, you just need to be sure to create Beans that match the value object descriptors on the client side to make sure things translate properly back and forth. 
This should get you started:
http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/BlazeDS:Release_Notes

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the Spring BlazeDS samples - http://www.springsource.org/spring-flex It has some good examples of a full BlazeDS environment.